# btrfs partition won't mount after upgrading 64bit Ubuntu 11.10 laptop

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, mount, 11.10, btrfs

I have tried many ideas from the net, but none of them work.

This looks correct and in good order

```
**sudo btrfs filesystem show /dev/sda2**
failed to read /dev/sr0
Label: none  uuid: daeedc21-7449-4b4a-ae55-e58a5a28a504
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 4.02GB
    devid    1 size 32.60GB used 22.54GB path /dev/sda2
```

When I do a scan it returns what looks like a reasonable response:

```
**sudo btrfsck -s /dev/sda2**
found 4321669120 bytes used err is 0
total csum bytes: 4187576
total tree bytes: 23400448
total fs tree bytes: 12083200
btree space waste bytes: 6789166
file data blocks allocated: 4786331648
 referenced 4126896128
Btrfs Btrfs v0.19
```

However, even when I use the degraded mount option, I still get an error in the logs, and it would appear that a good superblock can not be found.

```
**sudo mount -o degraded -t btrfs /dev/sda2 /home**
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

**Error seen in the log:**

```
[  647.710937] device fsid 4a4b497421dceeda-4a5285a8ae555ae devid 1 transid 20368 /dev/sda2
[  647.712760] btrfs: allowing degraded mounts
[  647.714378] parent transid verify failed on 7051943936 wanted 20368 found 20375
[  647.714784] parent transid verify failed on 7051943936 wanted 20368 found 20375
[  647.715182] parent transid verify failed on 7051943936 wanted 20368 found 20375
[  647.760270] btrfs: open_ctree failed
[ 1081.410560] device fsid 4a4b497421dceeda-4a5285a8ae555ae devid 1 transid 20368 /dev/sda2
```

This lappy has not had any sudden power-offs, and was just shutdown and restarted as normal after the daily updates. I am using a Kingston SSD drive, but have been for months, so don't think this should be a contributing factor.

Any pointers greatly received, as I would prefer to keep using btrfs, rather than having to move back to ext4.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem and fixed it by running `sudo btrfsctl -a` (apparently running `sudo btrfs device scan` will work too, though I haven't tried it).

Unfortunately you need to run that after each boot. I found an automatic solution [here](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/linux-btrfs/2010/4/16/6884594), though from what I understand it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: `sudo btrfs device scan` doesn't work, and `btrfsctrl` is deprecated and disappeared. I thought it is replaced by the former command, but it doesn't work as you see…

Answer (score 0):

try mounting it `-o recovery`

You can also built the fsck.btrfs tool from here

https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrfs_source_repositories#btrfs-progs_Git_Repository

which will allow you to `./btrfsck --repair /dev/devicename`

note: you also will need to `apt-get install build-essential`

I was getting kernel "BUG"s, which you are not getting, but after using btrfs for quite a while I finially went back to ext4 after too many problems.